# Identical control binding across multiple controls

Tags: wpf, validation, controls

I have an application where I want to apply the same binding for validation across all textboxes.

```
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="71,76,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="229" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=errorMsgStyle}">            
**<TextBox.Text>
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Text" UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <Validators:RequiredFieldValidationRule ErrorMessage="Required field1"/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>**

    </TextBox>
```

The portion within (**) is same for all textboxes, but this is something that I don't want to repeat copying and pasting for all.

Unfortunately, the application does not use MVVM. Can someone please tell me how to define this validation binding as a template (or something like it) and used everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by setting the binding in a style.

```
     <Style x:Key="ValidatedTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Text">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Text" UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <Validators:RequiredFieldValidationRule ErrorMessage="Required field1"/>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

of course, all of the textboxes will be bound to the same source... this may be what you want though.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am already using the "Style" property in the TextBox. Can you please tell me how I can use the other one too?

Comment: You'd have to inherit a new style from the existing one.  Look into the BasedOn property.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Binding x:Key="Validation" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Text" UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <Validators:RequiredFieldValidationRule ErrorMessage="Required field1"/>
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
</Window.Resources>
```

Example:

```
<TextBox Text="{StaticResource Validation}"/>
```

Comment: You cannot place a `Binding` in `Resources`.